# ASIHTTPRequest, request sent twice

Tags: iphone, ios, http, xcode4, asihttprequest

I´ve just started using ASIHTTPRequest for iOs and I have a small issue with it. All requests are sent twice to the server even though I only get one reply from the library to my delegate methods.

Both sync and async requests have this issue. I use Xcode 4 with ARC but have disabled it for ASIHTTPRequest by adding -fno-objc-arc as compiler flags.

Any idea what´s wrong..?

Code:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has bitten me too. I was using a GET request to validate a multi-use voucher code on a server. When we added a rate limitation for redeeming codes some customers reported hitting the limit before they should have. Turns out that some of the validations triggered two redeems.

Your request is using the GET method.

The default behavior when using GET is to allow persistent connections ([the Keep-Alive HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)).

When using a persistent connection your GET request might get retransmitted if something on the network looks wonky (that's a technical term) instead of the request just failing. This is usually desirable because GET requests often do not have any side effects on the server.

POST or PUT requests on the other hand default to not use a persistent connection and will not retransmit your operation, which could well be a credit card purchase or something else with significant side effects.

If you wish to prevent your ASIHTTPRequest GET sometimes sending 2 or more server requests (due to network issues outside your control) you can simply set this flag:

```
request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;
```

This should take care of the spurious GET duplicates on the server.

Comment: +1. After 1 year and a few months, a lifesaver. This should actually be marked as the correct answer, since it addresses the problem OP was having when he first asked the question.

Comment: I was seeing this with a POST as well.  I read through the code and didn't see any exclusion for a POST request.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your replies. I moved to the new MKNetworkKit and never looked back at ASIHttpRequest.  https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit

Øystein

Comment: Reviving an ancient post: I just inherited some code using MKNetworkKit and am getting multiple requests when authentication fails. Any idea how to prevent this behavior with MKNetworkKit?

Answer (score 1):

It might be sending a HEAD request to fetch the response size followed by a GET request to actually get the content. See [this section of the documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#accurate_progress_vs_simple_progress) for more information.

Comment: Thanks to your comment here I was able to determine the cause of a problem I've had with ASIHTTPRequest.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because persistent connections are in use, so you're seeing a failed request on a old connection followed by a working request on a new connection. (GregInYEG is also correct that it could be a HEAD request.)

If you gather a network trace using a tool like wireshark or charlesproxy then it would be possible to see exactly what is happening.